Highcharts - Reduce the padding/ space for labels in x-axis (multiple)
I have created a gantt chart with x-axis showing 3 axis time, week and month similar to the image below :

I want to reduce the space or reduce the height of storkes in the high chart ticks. If we see the text June ans July has more space on top and bottom.
I tried adding the below CSS:
  svg > g.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels.xaxis-week > text {
    transform: translate(0px, 10px);
}

svg > g.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels.xaxis-days > text {
    transform: translate(0px, 10px);
}

but it will just move the text but not reducing the height of the tick. I tried setting ticklength but it is not working as well.
I need to know if there is a way to achieve this as too much space is occupied by the boxes in the x-axis. Is there a way to set path dimensions or reduce stroke length for the same

You can simply use the labels.distance property inside of the x-axis object to increase or decrease the label padding:
xAxis: [{
    labels: {
        distance: 10
    }
}]

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cLv36u75/
API: https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.labels.distance

i tried this but not reflecting the UI
            {                 opposite: false,                 labels: {                     distance: 10,                     style: {                         fontSize: '9px',                         textOverflow: 'ellipsis',                         color: '#808080',                         whiteSpace: 'nowrap'                     }                 }             }

Can you reproduce this problem in an online edtior? You can start by editing above jsfiddle demo.
